# Visualize accuracy in a longitude latitude plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I used the ggplot library to plot my data (longitude, latitude, compass heading and gps accuracy of a mobile device):

```
data = st_as_sf(data, coords=c("longitude","latitude"), crs=2163)

ggplot(data) + 
      geom_sf(aes(size=accuracy), alpha=0.02) +
      geom_sf(aes(color=compass), size=.5)
```

I am looking for a solution concerning the accuracy: The accuracy value is given in meters. It describes the possible deviation from the player's position (the long-lat-data is measured via gps). I would like to have circle that cover the exact area of possible deviation in m.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the data to a projected CRS, such as `st_transform(data,2163)` if the area is in the US. Then use `st_buffer` to calculate the circle around each point. The `dist` parameter should be the radius, in meters.

Comment: This: `buffer <- st_buffer (data, data$accuracy)` does not work...

Comment: To determine why, you need to post a reproducible example with sample `data`...